# Stats for character in Apocalypse World

Tags: character-creation, apocalypse-world

I can't find anywhere how you generate the stats for the characters in Apocalypse World. Is it even part of the rules or can you just write whatever you want. If so, why would I put -2 in something when I can have +3 in everything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the playbooks. Step two (after NAME) is STATS, which tells you "Choose one set:" followed by a list of stat arrays that are unique to each playbook.

The playbooks were designed so that all the rules for players are in the playbook and the Moves sheet, and the rulebook is really only necessary for the MC. Playbooks are essentially guided pick-lists: do exactly what the playbook says, to the letter, and you'll have a character ready to play in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Ok coming from Dungeon World I was looking for a generic rule in the Character Creation chapter.

Comment: @MrJinPengyou DW is structured in some significantly different ways because it's a blend of D&D and AW. The 3-18 stats are a sacred cow of D&D, so they're kept and built on in DW, while AW doesn't need them. If you keep in mind that DW is an adaptation of AW and that how DW does things won't be a good guide for how AW was designed in the first place, you'll have an easier time of it.